# Selecting num_epochs value for the tutorial example in Tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, linear-regression

The tensorflow tutorial on https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started has an example for estimator where they are creating the linear regressor model as shown below:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np 

feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column("x", shape=[1])]

estimator = tf.estimator.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=feature_columns)

x_train = np.array([1., 2., 3., 4.])
y_train = np.array([0, -1., -2., -3.])
x_eval = np.array([2., 5., 8., 1.])
y_eval = np.array([-1.01, -4.1, -7, 0.])

input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn({"x":x_train}, y_train, batch_size = 4, num_epochs=None, shuffle=True)
train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn({"x":x_train}, y_train, batch_size = 4, num_epochs=1000, shuffle=False)
eval_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn({"x":x_eval}, y_eval, batch_size = 4, num_epochs=1000, shuffle = False)

estimator.train(input_fn=input_fn, steps=1000)

train_metrics = estimator.evaluate(input_fn = train_input_fn)
eval_metrics = estimator.evaluate(input_fn = eval_input_fn)

print("train metrics: %r"% train_metrics)
print("eval metrics: %r"% eval_metrics)
```

My question is for 'train_input_fn' and 'eval_input_fn' why do we need to select 'num_epochs=1000'?

These are the outputs with different 'num_epochs' values:

num_epochs=1000

```py
train metrics: {'global_step': 1000, 'loss': 4.3708383e-08, 'average_loss': 1.0927096e-08}
eval metrics: {'global_step': 1000, 'loss': 0.010135064, 'average_loss': 0.002533766}
```

num_epochs=1

```py
train metrics: {'global_step': 1000, 'loss': 9.6500253e-07, 'average_loss': 2.4125063e-07}
eval metrics: {'global_step': 1000, 'loss': 0.010293347, 'average_loss': 0.0025733367}
```

I was expecting the value of 'loss' and 'average_loss' to be same when num_epochs=1. Can someone help me understand this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition is correct:

```
0.002533766 == 0.010293347 / 4
```

or

```
0.002533766 == 0.010293347 / x_eval.shape[0]
```

or

```
average_loss == epoch_loss / x_eval.shape[0]
```

However, I too am stumped about why selecting multiple epochs for evaluation makes sense, esp. if `x_eval.shape[0] == batch_size`. Perhaps they were just trying to show that the function `tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn` accepts `num_epochs` as a parameter.